# Update color in customView by setter

Tags: android, android-custom-view, setter

I have CustomView and it works ok.
Now i need to change some item color by code.
So here is the code i have:

```
CustomView cv = new CustomView(mContext);
cv.setItemColor(Color.parseColor("#e77400"));
```

inside of my customView i add method:

```
public void setItemColor(int color){
        mItemColorDefault = color;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
```

but after this nothing happen and customView does not refresh...
Please, help to fix this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no need to call `requestLayout()` unless the size of the `CustomView` is not changed. This method only relates to views positioning updates.
2. You must override the `onDraw()` method as it is the place when your view is drawn. The `invalidate()` method causes `onDraw()` to invoked.
   Use the `mItemColorDefault` color to draw your view with it in `onDraw()`.

Here is the example of custom view with `onDraw()` method overridden:

https://github.com/dawidgdanski/TicTacToe/blob/master/game/src/main/java/pl/dawidgdanski/tictactoe/game/view/TicTacToeView.java

Hope this helps somehow.